# Django query syntax (must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple)

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to do a select

```
query = "select * from snmptt order by id desc limit %s", limit
cursorMYSQL.execute(query)
```

I get limit from a form

```
limit = form_limit.cleaned_data['limit']
```

I already used this syntax (, instead of %) for an insert and it worked, so I don't get why it's not working now.

Thanks!

Comment: But first let me ask you a question, why are you creating a cursor and executing a such a simple query manually when you are using Django?

Comment: What happens if you change it to `"select * from snmptt order by id desc limit %s" % limit`?

Comment: @cezar It's a bad idea to use `"..." % limit`. It might work, but it's insecure and leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: What do you mean? How could that happen?

Comment: The comments here are not the best place to explain SQL injection, so I recommend you do some research. Briefly, if the parameters are not escaped, the danger is that a user can execute something like `select * from snmptt order by id desc limit 5; drop table snmptt;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query and params should be separate arguments to the execute method.

```
query = "select * from snmptt order by id desc limit %s"
params = [limit]
cursorMYSQL.execute(query, params)
```

Comment: @cezar you can do the entire thing in one line if you want, but I think the longer version is clearer, especially as a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my previous comment instead of just editing it. Yes, the longer version is more verbose and more comprehensive. Just a remark, wouldn't it be better for `params` to be a tuple. In the documentation I saw tuples in the prepared statements.

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference practically whether you use a list or a tuple. In this case, where there is only one parameter, I used `[limit]` because it's clearer that `(limit,)`.

Comment: I really like the long version, it's cleaner and clearer but, it's not working either I'm getting the same error.

Comment: If it's still not working, please update your question and add the full traceback, please post the value of `limit` as well.